# Convert innerHTML to text and put into textarea not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to take inner HTML (both tags and text) of an element and put it in textarea, but somehow it is not working. How can I make it work and why is this not working?

HTML:

```
<div id="element">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

JS:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#element").html("<textarea>"+$("#element").text($("#element").html())+"</textarea>");
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xhynjfyf/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#element").text($("#element").html())
```

there's your problem
it should be

```
$("#element").text()
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xhynjfyf/2/)

**edit:**

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xhynjfyf/3/)

Comment: `I want to take inner HTML of an element and put it in textarea` Or maybe `$("#element").html()`, not sure what OP is expecting here

Comment: I want HTML tags and text to appear in textarea when button clicked

Comment: maybe he means html inside textarea, as in text with tags ? wysiwyg kind of thing. if thats what you mean, op, thats not how it works unfortunately.

Comment: so here in `textarea` shold be  `<p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p>`

Comment: @NocturnalPenguin yeah that is what I mean :)

Comment: I updated the fiddle so you can see the result html tags will only show as text inside textarea